# What do these lines from The Decline of the West, mean?

Tags: language, historiography

> the means to identify dead forms is mathematical law, the means whereby to understand living forms is analogy.

What does this mean? When I looked it up I got a history textbook and it was talking about how this phrase is "comparative morphology" I don't have a history degree. When I looked up "comparative morphology (history)" nothing relevant came up.

> and is not archaeology itself an expression of the sense that history is repetition?

I have genuinely no idea what the author is trying to say with this.

Is it possible to read this book with no previous knowledge of historicity? I don't wanna keep putting tons of thought into deciphering this coded language. Any tips?

Comment: ah fair enough will post it again, should I delete it here?

Comment: Yes, delete here and post on English. Also, quote more or link to the book.

Comment: I'd start with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Decline_of_the_West#Meaning_of_history) which discusses the overview, forms and morphology. "Spengler's philosophy of history, using a methodology which approached history and historical comparisons on the basis of civilizational forms and structure"  use math to study prior forms; for current/active living forms, you need to use an analogy.  Note from Wikipedia that his approach is ... not widely supported...

Comment: I suspect you'll also have to review Goethe and Nietsche, which are not light reading. And perhaps inoculate yourself against 1920's German far right ideology.

Comment: Well, its possible its History jargon, so ELU wouldn't be any better. However, *neither site is going to do well with only part of a sentence*. Personally, I'd prefer to see the entire paragraph for context.

Comment: "I have genuinely no idea what the author is trying to say with this".  Heh. You assume that *he* knew and that it's more than muddy thinking.

Comment: @MCW Spengler was a reactionary, true. But here, it seems sufficient to read these cliched phrases as he *himself* repeats them in his writings. And indeed, the surrounding context of both passages, and ironically the analogous repetition of his own forms should provide enough hints to what he means (not just p4, but also eg 173 for arch; p4, 14, 620.) The *biologising* far right ideology (incl genius cult, matter of fact quite close to Nietzschean thought, but priors as well) then should come 'naturally' ;) (Although, *that* might take things for this site 'too far…')